# How to print the effective Babel config for a project directory?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, babel-loader, transpiler

We're working on fixing a `.babelrc.js` file that seemingly doesn't load plugins/presets as intended, and I'm wondering if there's any way we can print out the effective configuration for a given directory? Without that ability, it's like flying blind.

Or is there somewhere we can modify in our `node_modules` to add a `console.log()` to output the effective configuration?

Answer (score 1):

See https://babeljs.io/docs/configuration#print-effective-configs

```
BABEL_SHOW_CONFIG_FOR=./src/myComponent.jsx npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using any other transpiler like typescript. If you use Babel only, the dist files must be generated according to the Babel configuration. There are 2 ways to test it.

1. Try executing Babel on a single file. You  can check the output file if the plugin works as expected.

   `npx babel script.js --out-file script-compiled.js`
2. If you are using typescript, add typescript presets and check
   `npx babel  script.js --out-file script-compiled.js --extensions ".ts,.tsx"`